# How to properly type assets for ESLint in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

How should I properly type assets imported from another files, I am trying to create dev env with esbuild, react with typescript and ESLint and when I import images from another files I get ESLint warning about

```
Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

Should I switch off this rule, or is there a better way to deal with it?
This is my code

```
import React from "react";
import x from "../assets/photo/kdmocg.jpg";
import gif from "../assets/img/work-life-balance.gif";

interface SizeProps {
  width: string;
}

export const TestComponen: React.FC<SizeProps> = ({ width }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img alt="x" src={x} className="handsome" style={{ width }} />
      <h1>Hello super World!!!</h1>
      <img alt="x" src={gif} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: First of all, TypeScript needs to know that file extension can be imported from so make sure you have (in a global file) `declare module '*.png' {const _: string: export default _;`

Comment: More importantly, the rule `value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment` is TypeScript's domain, not ESLint's. There's lots of unfortunate duplication, not to mention project template shipping with default lint configs which include rules that encourage you to write terrible typescript. In this case, it's not so much a bad role as a redundant one. Disable that rule!